# How to use multithreading when copying data from one file converting it to something then pasting it in another file

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Question I want to use threading to convert a txt doc (first.txt) that has temperatures in C to F and save the output to another file (second.txt) below is what I have so far but, I am unable to get it to work properly any help would be much appreciated.

```
import os
import sys
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


class ConverterWorker(Thread):
  def __init__(self, queue):
      Thread.__init__(self)
      self.queue = queue

  def run(self):
      while True:
        temps = self.queue.get()
        self.queue.task_done()



class copy_and_convert_temps(object):


  def run_it(self):
    copy_and_convert_temps().do_them_together()


  def do_them_together(self):
    first_txt = "first.txt"
    second_txt = "second_txt"
    queue = Queue()
    for x in range(2):
      worker = ConverterWorker(queue)
      worker.daemon = True
      worker.start()
      with open(first_txt, "r") as f1:
        with open(second_txt, "w") as f2:
          f_temps = f1.readlines()
          for xt in f_temps:
            ct = copy_and_convert_temps().convert_temps(xt)
            queue.put((ct))
          queue.join()
          f2.writelines(ct)


  def convert_temps(self, temp):
    for xi in temp:
      f_to_c = 9.0/5.0 * int(xi) + 32

      yield (str(f_to_c) + "\n")






copy_and_convert_temps().run_it()
```

## first text

```
2
12
-3
-10
5
```

## second text

```
   ^should have converted C temps to F 
   ?
   ?
   ?
   ?
   ?
   ?
```

Comment: Your code does not make much sense. It does not run at all due to ValueErrors.  Your worker thread does not seem to be doing anything. It reads something from a queue but does not appear to be doing anything with it. Etc

Comment: I know that's why I asked the question because, I can't seem to get it to work. @Hannu

Comment: This code snippet has so many issues it would take a complete rewrite to work.   You start your thread correctly, but then you should make the tread do something. For example calculate the result, or whatever you expect it to do.  Then you have convert_temps using yield, making it a generator, which is fine, but then you should use it as such. Your statement ct = copy_and_convert_temps().convert_temps(xt) doesn't mean anything. Do you mean ct = self.convert_temps(xt) leaving the generator issue. What do you intend to put in queue? etc.  I don't think this question can be answered as such.